.NET MAUI: The Content page CollectionView items collide with each other
When I try to scroll top to bottom at that time, the CollectionView items collide on the Content page on the iOS platform, but it works fine on the Android platform. Below, I am adding a screenshot and Screen record of this issue.
Screenshot:

Screen Record:
screen record link
I am using CollectionView for this content page, the below is the code:
<CollectionView  
    Grid.Row="1"
    ZIndex="5"
    Margin="5,0"
    IsVisible="false"
    SelectionMode="Single"
    BackgroundColor="Transparent"
    x:Name="AccountInvoicelistview"
    ItemsLayout="VerticalGrid"
    SelectionChanged="invoice_ItemTapped">
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackLayout 
                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                Orientation="Vertical" 
                BackgroundColor="{Binding invoice.BGColor}"
                Padding="5">
                
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="75*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="25*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <Label 
                        Text="{Binding invoice.title, Converter={StaticResource specialCharactorConverter}}"
                    </Label>

                    <Label 
                        Text="{Binding invoice.status, Converter={StaticResource specialCharactorConverter}}"
                    </Label>
                </Grid>

                <Label 
                    Text="{Binding createdLocation.locationName, Converter={StaticResource specialCharactorConverter}}"
                </Label>

                <StackLayout
                    Margin="5,0"
                    HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                    VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                    IsVisible="{Binding LockedVisibility}"
                    Orientation="Horizontal">

                    <Label 
                        Text="{Binding lockedLocation.locakedStatusText, Converter={StaticResource specialCharactorConverter}}"
                    </Label>

                    <Image 
                        Style="{StaticResource RequestHeaderImageStyle}" 
                        Source="ic_green_tick_xx.png">
                    </Image>
                </StackLayout>

                <StackLayout
                    Orientation="Horizontal"
                    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">

                    <Label 
                        Text="{Binding invoice.Amount, StringFormat='${0:F0}'}"
                    </Label>

                    <Label 
                        Text="{Binding invoice.dueDate, StringFormat='Due date: {0:F0}', 
                    </Label>
                </StackLayout>
                
                <BoxView
                    HeightRequest="1"
                    Margin="0,5,0,0"
                    BackgroundColor="#cecece"
                    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
            </StackLayout>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>

Can you please provide me with a solution to resolve this issue? This issue is only on iOS platform.
Update
I have created a sample project and uploaded it here.
Expected UI:


If you add the margin value in  <StackLayout                      Margin="5,0"                      HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"                      VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand"                      IsVisible="{Binding LockedVisibility}"                      Orientation="Horizontal">, or set 
<Label
Text="{Binding invoice.Amount, StringFormat='${0:F0}'}"
With the new margin property, will the view layout change?

@SeanHe-MSFT We have added margin for both stacklayouts, but no change in UI.

Is this related to the system version? Have you tried other iOS versions?

@Leon We are using .NET 7.0 and the problem occurs in iOS simulator. macOS version 14.4.1

@user10627299 We have added a sample project on the question, could you please check that?

I recommend using a Grid for the layout, don't use a StackLayout when exact positioning is required.

Set Grid with Height instead of inner stack layout of Listview

Yes, CollectionView items collide when scrolling the CollectionView.
As a workaround, you may try the following code to set the row definitions for the SearchBar and the CollectionView. Using Auto to the Height Property of RowDefinition,
<Grid
    Margin="0,0,0,5"
    Padding="3"
    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

<Frame 
     Grid.Row="0"
...


<CollectionView  
     Grid.Row="1"
...

For more info, you may refer to Rows and columns.
